# How to send/receive a string via BlueTooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have 3 edit texts. The data from these edittexts are concatenated to a single string. I want to send this string over bluetooth from my phone using my application to the same application in another phone.

code for bluetooth manager and fetching paired list of devices is:

```
   if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), 0);
            Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Turned ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Alredy ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

       //show the list of paired devices...
        startActivity(new Intent(this,DeviceList.class));
   }
}

    public void list(View v){
        pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
            list.add(bt.getName());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

. Now i want to send that string from my app in a phone to the same app in another phone. That is suppose i have connected both phones (say A and B) having this app. I want to send a string (say "123") from A to B

I went through a few tutorials in the net. All i have understood is that this requires a socket and a unique key to identify the application. How may i do this?
Please Elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only be able to search for available bluetooth devices by the code that you've put up. You are right, you'll need to establish a socket connection to talk to the other device. Implement the code given in the example in this link and you should be able to see your string on another device. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html